# How to divide this into two elements?

Tags: html, css

```css
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    #sub { display: none; }
    #sub2 { width:50%; }
    #sub2 > div:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name - "; }
    #sub2 > div:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name - "; }
    #sub2 > div:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Middle Name - "; }
}
```

```html
<div id="Main">
<section id="sub">
    <div>First Name</div>
    <div>Last Name</div>
    <div>Middle Name</div>
</section>
<section id="sub2">
    <div>foo first</div>
    <div>foo Last</div>
    <div>foo Middle</div>
</section>
</div>
```

When the screen size is of a mobile, I apply css that hides the `#sub` and put the width of `#sub2` as `50%`. Then I use `div:nth-of-type(1):before {content: "First Name - "; }` etc to display the sub headers before the values. Everything works, but the result is something like this:

```
First Name - first
Last Name - Last
Middle Name - middle
```

I cannot align the values because what ever style I am setting it's going for the entire "First Name - first". Not just the value "first". How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please show how do you want it to look like?

Comment: Please add the CSS you are using.

Comment: @ibtarek want all the values of sub2 to be aligned.

Comment: please post your desired behavior and your current CSS. Needless to say you're using a really convoluted approach, but maybe there's some method behind the madness

Comment: @SamsonBujju, glad to help if you help me understand what you're looking for. Please add a figure and include your CSS

Comment: @SamsonBujju I've fixed up your post to make it a little easier to understand. Could you edit your post and add the expected output? You should be able to duplicate the code block I put in for you near the end of the post (with "First Name - first" in it) and align as necessary with spaces. Also, be sure to add a paragraph before it noting that it is the expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can float #sub to the left, then #sub2 will be next to #sub. Then you can style #sub and #sub2 separably.

```css
#sub span {display:none;}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #sub {width:120px;float:left;}
  #sub span {display:inline-block;}
}
```

```html
<div id="Main">
<section id="sub">
    <div>First Name <span> - </span></div>
    <div>Last Name <span> - </span></div>
    <div>Middle Name <span> - </span></div>
</section>
<section id="sub2">
    <div>foo first</div>
    <div>foo Last</div> 
    <div>foo Middle</div>
</section>
</div>
```